# Read txt data and import into datagridview vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have txt file that contain data something like this

```
EN^FN^SN^GN^SQ^I48-14^000042^2014-11-19^15:13:45^2014-11-19^^
```

Expected result in datagridview

```
EN         FN         SN            GN           SQ
I48-14     000042     2014-11-19    15:13:45     2014-11-19
```

In design form I have 1 button to browse the file directory, 1 textbox to show file name, of course one 1 datagridview to show the result of conversion 
I'm having this error line

```
Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)

* No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.
```

This is the code I've tied with no success

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    Dim fName As String = ""
    Dim Ex As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    'Ex.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    Ex.Filter = "(*.csv)|*.CSV|(*.txt)|*.txt"
    Ex.FilterIndex = 2
    Ex.RestoreDirectory = True
    If (Ex.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        fName = Ex.FileName
    End If
    Me.TextBox1.Text = fName
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String
    If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine, "^")
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: The error is telling you what's wrong.  You need to add columns before you can add rows.  Loop through the first five elements and add the columns, then the next five is used for the row.

Comment: Or format your text file such that the first line would be your columns and the rest would be your rows.

Comment: Turn Option Strict On its your friend. Also look into classes... Also what happens when a user picks a .csv file kabam! Your current code isnt handling this. Either filter it or handle the data.

Comment: @Adam I think your input file format needs to be better. For example, on first line the columns name, and then the rows data. Something similar to CSV file format.

Comment: Now I am totally lost. Perhaps someone can help with the code please. Sorry I'm very new to VB.NET any help would be appreciate

Comment: Do you have the option of changing your input file format?  If not do you know for a fact before reading it that there will be five columns or are you expected to work out how many columns there are from the content?  It's never a good idea to create an algorithm based on a single example.  You have to know the rules that ALL examples will follow.

Answer (score 0):

this error

```
Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)

* No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.
```

comes when your datagridview does not have any columns so

```
Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
   TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
   SplitLine = Split(TextLine, "^")
Dim cl1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
With cl1
    .HeaderText = "SomeRandaomeName"
    .Name = "SomeRandaomeName"
    .Width = 120
    .ReadOnly = True
End With

Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
Loop
```

it just a idea for you you can change it SomeRandaomeName with the values coming from SplitLine

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim fName As String = ""
    Dim Ex As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Ex.Filter = "(*.csv)|*.CSV|(*.txt)|*.txt"
    Ex.FilterIndex = 2
    Ex.RestoreDirectory = True
    If (Ex.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        fName = Ex.FileName
    End If
    Me.TextBox1.Text = fName
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String
    If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()

        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("EN", "EN")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("FN", "FN")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("SN", "SN")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("GN", "GN")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("SQ", "SQ")

        DataGridView1.Columns.Item("EN").Width = 120
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item("FN").Width = 120
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item("SN").Width = 120
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item("GN").Width = 120
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item("SQ").Width = 120

        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine, "^")
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If
```